# Tracing cable in wall

Tags: wiring, cables

I will try to explain my situation as simple as possible :)
In my house, one side of telephone installation cable (it has few wires inside) comes from wall and I have access to it. I know approximately where other side of that cable is in house, but I don't have access to it because it is in wall. I need to find exact position where it ends in wall. Is it possible to trace that cable from one side of it (which is accessible to me) to other side (which is not accessible because it ends somewhere in wall)? If yes, which tools I need?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A time-domain reflectometer would help. An x-ray wall scanner ([yes that's a thing](https://www.amazon.com/DEWALT-DCT419S1-Hand-Held-Scanner/dp/B00ODN0VW2)) would be more direct. And then there's always the simple answer of getting out a sledgehammer and breaking down the wall!

Comment: Or, for a cheap, (hopefully) non-destructive, but potentially **dangerous** approach, energize the cable with mains voltage and use one of those non-contact voltage detector probes.

Comment: Are you looking for a "fox and hound" cable tracer?

Comment: @Felthry , thanks for reply. I'm afraid that instruments you mentioned are expensive for me :) I need some cheap solution. I can't use destructive methods using hammer because I'm afraid that AC mains cables go near that telephone cable :) That's why I need almost exact location of end of cable so I can safely use hammer.

Comment: @The Photon, sorry but I don't know what is "fox and hound" cable tracer :(

Comment: Did you try googling it?

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't know those existed! Pretty clever way to do it. Obvious in hindsight, but I wouldn't have thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telephone industry has long used a device called a "Toner". This is a two part device the first of which is connected to the cable to generate a traceable tone. The second part is the tracer. Normally it is used to identify a particular pair on a cable but it that can, with fairly good accuracy, be used to trace the location of the wire.

Inexpensive versions of Toners can be found on the web including one for ~$20 from Walmart.com.